# Taking the dual of this non-standard linear program

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I am just beginning to learn linear programming have a question about taking the dual of a non-standard LP specifically the one below:

$\min M\\
2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 \leq M \\
2x_1 - x_2 + x_3 \leq M\\
x_1 -5x_2 -x_3 \leq M\\
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 2\\
x_1 \geq 0\\
x_2 \geq 0\\
x_3 \geq 0\\
$

I'm confused because $x$ doesn't show up in the objective. This might not have a feasible solution (I think it does) but even if it doesn't, I'm more interested in finding out how to take the dual of such problems than what the exact dual for this LP is. Please explain any reasoning and steps in taking this dual. Thanks!

Comment: Imagine that $x_1,x_2,x_3$ appear in the objective function with coefficient zero, and follow the usual dualization algorithm. By the way, a program in which the objective function is constant is called a *feasibility* program, and solving general linear programs can be reduced to the case of determining feasibility of linear programs.

Comment: What about resolving the $M$'s? Subtract it from one side so that $2x_1 + 3x_2 + 4x_3 - M \leq 0$?

Comment: That depends on whether $M$ is a variable or a constant; I assumed it's a constant. In any case, you just follow the algorithm. If the algorithm you learnt in class is confusing you, there are many versions of it online.

Comment: If $M$ is a variable, as it appears to be, call it $x_4$ and your confusion should hopefully decrease. The first constraint should give you a hint on whether this new variable $x_4$ can be negative, in case you want to get everything into standard form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there nothing said about M ? If I assume M is a constant, then the dual problem is as follows:

$\text{max} \ Mu_1+Mu_2+Mu_3+Mu_4  $

$2u_1+2u_2+u_3+u_4 \leq 0\quad \quad (\color{blue}{x_1})$

$3u_1-u_2-5u_3+u_4 \leq 0\quad \quad (\color{blue}{x_2})$

$4u_1+u_2-u_3+u_4 \leq 0\quad \ \ \quad (\color{blue}{x_3})$

$u_1,u_2,u_3 \leq 0$

$u_4$ is a free variable

I have done the conversion by using the table below. Because of the primal problem is a min-problem, you have to read the table from right to left. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

[image]